# SQL: How to create a table when the condition is that the data in two columns from two different rows for the same ID be the same?

Tags: sql, sas

I have a table of duplicates.
I'd like to create a new table of duplicates where two columns: (1)start_date (2)return_date are the same. E.G. where start_date = return_date
Issue: the start_date = return_date are on different rows for the same ID.

Data example:

```
ID  Start_Date   Return_date
A   11/1/21      12/15/21
A   12/15/21     12/20/21
B   11/1/21      12/22/22
B   12/25/22     12/30/22
```

In this example, I would want ID A to be pulled into my new dataset, because ID A has a start_date = return_date. (12/15/21)

Here's one examples of many that I've tried and failed.

```
proc sql;
create table new as
select distinct ID, start_date, return_date
from 
old_table
where (start_date = return_date);
```

Comment: What error message are you getting? And which SQL flavor is this one? I have a feeling the issue is your syntax is not correct

Comment: I'm using SQL in SAS studio, so Proc Sql.  No error message, just an empty table.

Comment: Potential syntax errors aside, this is not going to do what you want. `where (start_date = return_date)` only looks at a single row. THat condition is never true in your sample data.

Comment: Thanks, good to know that a where statement only applies to each individual row. Would a better approach be to flatten the file to get one ID, and then create Start_date1, Start_date 2, etc.? Or are there approaches to pull duplicates across rows for the same ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will only return records where the start and return date are the same in the same record.

To get what you want you need to `join` the table with itself to be able to combine records with the same id. Then you will check that the start date of one of the tables matches any return date of the other table, filtered by the same id. Like:

```sql
select a.id, a.start_date, b.return_date
from old_table a inner join old_table b on a.id = b.id 
where a.start_date = b.return_date;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/353f12/1/0

Hope that helps